Number of occurrences of the names of tannaim in various books
Does anyone happen to know of a place where someone has counted the occurrences of the names of the Tannaim in the different books of rabbinic literature (e.g. Mishnah, Tosefta, Sifra, Sifrei etc.)?
I'm doing research into which sages where included in different parts of the literature, so I am trying to find out the frequency of references to the different tannaim.

1 - Michael Sperling has compiled a detailed dataset of spreadsheets on Google Drive for counting total mentions of Tannaim in the Mishna and Tosefta as is indicated in his paper Mishna-Tosefta Named Entity Statistical Analysis.
For starters you can take a look at his spreadsheet that lists the occurrences of Tannaim sorted in descending order by Mishna-count.
In the aforementioned article, he writes that he derived his data from three independent lists: one manually created from Aharon Hyman, Sefer Toldot
Tana’im ve-Amora'im (mentioned in the comment above); The Bonayich Data Base of Personalities in Rabbinic
Literature; a list previously compiled by himself from web sources. He has also cautioned that the data can contain some mistakes and that it was based on the Sefaria Mishna text.
2 - In addition to the Wikipedia resource for Aharon Hyman's sefer, the digitization of that sefer is also being worked on at Wikisource.
