Names of Tannaim and Amoraim
I am looking to find in BavaKamma the different names, how many times they appear and whom they argue with. I don’t have bar Ilan etc…
Perhaps is there a list of all tanaim and amoraim and then I can programmatically search and build the index myself.

See Rabbi Aharon Heiman's תולדות תנאים ואמוראים https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D.

also see this related question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/143193/number-of-occurrences-of-the-names-of-tannaim-in-various-books/

@Harel13 Thank you - here is a more specifically useful link like urs but with all child links for sections and names: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D

Get the English text of the Mishneh and take every capitalized word before the word "said" and that should get you most of your Tannaim

@ClintEastwood That would only be Tannaim in English not Amoraim, but I already found the answer. Thanks.

Here is a list in hebrew of Tanaim and Amoraim:
https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D

Who's Who In the Talmud by Shulamit Friedman is a good reference.
Aiding Talmud Study by R' Aryeh Carmel has a list.
There are multiple digital Talmuds available other than Bar Ilan to enable your search.

Sadly, because I need the names to do the next step, the names would need to be digitally available and easily catalogued, which book formats likely won't allow. Also R' Aryeh Carmel's list is very short AFAIK

It wouldn't take THAT long to type them up, or you could scan the pages. Or you could contact the publisher and request the data. Or.... you could try Google: https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14240-tannaim-and-amoraim

Sorry your resources are either english (too many variations and I'd like hebrew) or too short. I will post an answer.
